# global variable undefined after setting it

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run this peice of code but it says that the `a` variable is `undefined` even though as you can see I have very clearly defined it and it has to be a global variable as it is changed after each loop

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;

window.setInterval(function(){
    alert(a);
    if(a == 1){
        document.getElementById('pic2').style.opacity = '1';
        document.getElementById('pic1').style.opacity = '0';
        var b = 1;
        var a = 2;
    }
    if(a == 2){
        document.getElementById('pic2').style.opacity = '0';
        document.getElementById('pic1').style.opacity = '1';
        var b = 2;
        var a = 1;
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a global variable?  If this code is within any sort of function (onload?) then the variable is not global due to the `var` before it.  Not to mention that you aren't changing the global (if it is global) because you are again using `var` to declare a new local.

Comment: no its its just in the head of the page in script tags

Comment: You're using `var` inside a function. That's not global.

Comment: Note that the code does not do what you probably think it does. The declaration of `a` and `b` within the interval callback hide the original ("global") declaration. Therefore, `a` and `b` will never change.

Comment: okay but that still doesnt solve the first problem im guessing putting window. before it will change the global value?

Comment: Yes, assigning to `window` will make it global but that's only necessary if the original declarations at the top are actually inside a function. The way your code shows it, they're not in a function, so all you'd need to do is remove the `var` from the ones in the interval callback.

Comment: okay well that worked on the first loop but didnt change the global on the second so 'a' is still 1 on the second loop

Answer (score 7):

It is because you are redeclaring your variable. Removing the vars from within the setInterval function fixes this issue.

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;

window.setInterval(function(){
    alert(a);
    if(a == 1){
        document.getElementById('pic2').style.opacity = '1';
        document.getElementById('pic1').style.opacity = '0';
        b = 1;
        a = 2;
    }
    if(a == 2){
        document.getElementById('pic2').style.opacity = '0';
        document.getElementById('pic1').style.opacity = '1';
        b = 2;
        a = 1;
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: The important concept here is "variable hoisting".  Even though the `var a` is lower in the function, the declaration of the local `a` is hoisted causing the `alert` to alert the local (yet to be defined) and not the global.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

Comment: Although this snippet answers the question, they code still does not work. The alert will always display '1' and the logic to change the value of 'a' inside the if statements will both be called.

Comment: It doens't work because it should be an `else if`.  When `a` is 1, the first `if` changes it to 2 but the 2nd `if` then executes setting it back to 1.

Comment: Yep just realised that :) This solves it as you says. http://jsfiddle.net/wta6fph9/1/

Comment: Good to hear! I would suggest marking the answer as resolved to help others in the future.